# Using connection string in ASP.Net MVC controller to retrieve records

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm

I am trying to retrieve records in my index ActionResult but keep getting a "The name 'connectionString' does not exist in the current context" error. Please see below code:

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector;

using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Web;

using System.Web.Mvc;

using TestMVCApp.DAL;

using TestMVCApp.Models;

namespace TestMVCApp.Controllers
{

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var objDAL = new DAL_InvoicesEntity();
            List<InvoicesModel> invInfo = objDAL.RetriveRecords(connectionString);

            ViewBag.invInfo = invInfo;
            return View();
        } 
    } 
}
```

DAL class file:

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;

using TestMVCApp.Models;

using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;

using Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector;

using System.Linq;


namespace TestMVCApp.DAL
{

    public class DAL_InvoicesEntity
    {
        public List<InvoicesModel> RetriveRecords(string connectionString)
        {
            var svc = new CrmServiceClient(connectionString);

            var query = new QueryExpression()
            {
                EntityName = "new_invoices",
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("new_invoicesid", "ttt_customer", "ttt_invoiceid", "ttt_paymentreceived", "ttt_commission", "ttt_adminfee", "ttt_discountamount"),
                TopCount = 10
            };

            var invoices = svc.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities.ToList();

            var invoiceModels = invoices.Select(i =>
                new InvoicesModel
                {
                    InvoiceID = i.GetAttributeValue<Guid>("new_invoicesid"),
                    ClientName = i.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("ttt_customer"),
                    InvoiceNumber = i.GetAttributeValue<string>("ttt_invoiceid"),
                    AdminFee = i.GetAttributeValue<decimal>("ttt_adminfee"),
                    Discount = i.GetAttributeValue<decimal>("ttt_discountamount"),
                    PaymentReceived = i.GetAttributeValue<decimal>("ttt_paymentreceived")
                })
                .ToList();

            return invoiceModels;
        }
    }
}
```

Please assist if you can

Comment: Well you don't have any variable with name `connectionString` defined already, so what you are passing to this line as parameter `objDAL.RetriveRecords(connectionString);` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You should define `connectionString` variable before using it.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
        private const connectionString = "YourConnectionString";
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            var objDAL = new DAL_InvoicesEntity();
            List<InvoicesModel> invInfo = objDAL.RetriveRecords(connectionString);

            ViewBag.invInfo = invInfo;
            return View();
        } 
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to have a separate class like with a method to retrieve your connectionString then declare it before using it. I'm sure you wont want to go with declaring your connectionString as private in all your controllers.